# Make flex respect bootstrap column properties

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox

I have used `display: flex;` in order to make sure that my cells have the same height when I use `class="col-md-6"`. However this has caused my cells to not change when viewing content on different screen sizes. So how should I code flex to keep the height and also respect bootstrap's column properties?

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bw40owr8/)

Comment: Kind of funny that flex would come up this weekend. I've been "coding" a flexbox.css file to make my own workflow faster (both in my workplace and outside work). I've uploaded it to github, so I can get it anytime I need it, so I thought I can as well give the link to it, to you: https://github.com/fexell/Felix-Lib/tree/master/Flexbox . Hope it helps somehow.

Comment: First off, the code snippet should be within the question, second, use Bootstrap 4. It is based on Flexbox, which the old 3.xx is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably best to give up on the premade class and do your own. The flex property lets you choose a width and give it the options to shrink or grow according to how much space is in the container. This way, if a column is removed, the others will grow/shrink to fill in the rest of the space.

I gave up bootstrap when Flexbox became browser friendly and I haven't looked back. It saves me a lot of time and code. Here is an article to learn more about how magical flex is: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Notice the media query doesn't let flex kick in until the screen is larger than 500px. This is how I do mobile because it just stacked the divs the way the are naturally. You can do multiple media queries to control to .col width in various screen sizes so you can tailor the look for different devices.

*Please note: the code editor on stackoverflow needs to be expanded so the media query kicks in as your adjusting your browser size.*

```css
@media(min-width:500px){
  .flex{ display:flex; }
  .col{ flex: 1 1 16.6666667%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">

  <div class="col">
    <p>Column 1</p>
  </div><!-- col -->
  
    <div class="col">
      <p>Column 2</p>
    </div><!-- col -->
  
    <div class="col">
     <p>Column 3</p>
   </div><!-- col -->
  
    <div class="col">
     <p>Column 4</p>
    </div><!-- col -->
  
    <div class="col">
      <p>Column 1</p>
    </div><!-- col -->
  
    <div class="col">
      <p>Column 5</p>
    </div><!-- col -->
    
    <div class="col">
      <p>Column 6</p>
    </div><!-- col -->
    
</div><!-- flex -->
```